# How to open html file with anchor(#) in C# with default browser

Tags: c#, .net, html, uri, anchor

I am trying to open a contextual help file in c#.

When i specify no anchor, it works perfectly.

```
Process.Start("C:/Help/Help.htm")
```

But when i specify anchor, it does not open

```
Process.Start("C:/Help/Help.htm#_Toc342057538")
```

Internally it changes `'#'` to `'%23'` and the path becomes `"c:\Help.htm%23_Toc342057538"` which browser is unable to recognize.

Browser is successfully opening the path `"c:\Help.htm#_Toc342057538"`

How to stop this automatic conversion by [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx). The same behavior is observed, if i give the anchor label as another argument, or use [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class.

**EDIT**
Same behavior is observed, when i enter the string in Window Run. Following command also convert `#` to `%23`, which browser cannot recognize.

```
chrome c:/Help.htm#_Toc342057538
```

Comment: Have you tried opening the users default browser and passing the file as an argument (the second paramter in `Process.Start`)? An example of the default browser check is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707799/start-default-browser-windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my Windows 7 system, both of the following open C:\Help\Help.htm in Internet Explorer and scroll to the _Toc342057538 anchor:

```
Process.Start("iexplore", "file://C:/Help/Help.htm#_Toc342057538");
Process.Start("iexplore", @"C:\Help\Help.htm#_Toc342057538");
```

For Firefox and Chrome, only the `file` protocol seems to work:

```
Process.Start("firefox", "file://C:/Help/Help.htm#_Toc342057538");
Process.Start("chrome", "file://C:/Help/Help.htm#_Toc342057538");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. I just did it myself and working in internet explorer

```
string s = "file:///D:/tmp/test.html%23test";
      s = uri.UnescapeDataString(s);

      Process.Start(s);
```

Please let me know if it is working or not for you.

Comment: is your default browser firefox, mine is internet explorer and it seems to work properly in it

Comment: it has worked with file://D:... and not with file:///d:.... Seems like extra backslash was problem